# How to achieve lighting like this in Unity for 2D games?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, lighting, glow

How could I accomplish a lighting effect something similar to this game?:
[image]

I'm not talking about the shadows but about the glowing/lighting effect on the crystals and the torches.

Anyone got any clues?

[More images from the games steam page](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=122788084)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Unity, so I don't know what it has to offer for this specific problem, but I would create this effect with one of these methods:

- Implement a bloom shader. This is where the brightest pixels are taken, blurred, then drawn over the scene. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_(shader_effect)) is the Wikipedia page on that.
- Simply create a "glow" texture. This could be, for example, a blurred circle. Color it appropriately and draw it on top of the glowing objects using an additive blend mode.

Here is what I mean by "glow texture"

[image: glow texture example]

Comment: Glow texture is probably more appropriate than bloom for this kind of thing.  Bloom is more appropriate for cases where you want to grow out specular highlights or other dynamic lighting, but for static things like this the glow texture approach should work fine and should be less expensive unless you have a lot of overlapping light sources.  Also, for a sprite game like this you could simply bake the glow effect into the sprite itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new material, with shader Sprites > Diffuse.

Select all the objects you want to react to lighting, go to their Sprite Renderer and change the material to the one you just created.

Create a point/spot light at Z=-1 and you should see the light.

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/comments/1wrkv3/can_someone_explain_2d_lighting_for_me/)